# Force line return with \message

Tags: debugging

I am trying to use \message to debug my code; in particular, to print information to the console. For some reason it is not adding line returns after each invocation (see example below). How can I force the line returns in the log (console)? Thanks, Jorge.

Example code:

```
\message{I:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
\message{I: textfloatsep    = \the\floatsep}
\message{I: floatsep        = \the\floatsep}
\message{I:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
\show\show
```

Output in console:

```
I:------------------------------------------------------------------------------- I: textfloatsep = 12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt
I: floatsep = 12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt I:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> \show=\show.
l.73 \show\show

?
```

UPDATE: solution using \typeout:

```
\typeout{I:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
\typeout{I: \string\textfloatsep                                \space\space\space\space\space  = \the\textfloatsep}
\typeout{I: \string\floatsep        \space\space\space\space    \space\space\space\space\space  = \the\floatsep}
\typeout{I:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
\show\show
```

OUTPUT:

```
I:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I: \textfloatsep     = 12.0pt plus 2.39996pt minus 2.39996pt
I: \floatsep         = 12.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 2.0pt
I:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> \show=\show.
l.73 \show\show

?
```

Comment: if you are using latex you can use `^^J` or better  `\MessageBreak`

Comment: That solved it! Thanks again, David! BTW, is it possible to print a backslash within a \message? I can't get it to print e.g. "\textfloatsep   = ..."

Comment: but use `\typeout` rather than message to make each messag ecome on its own line

Comment: `\message{\textfloatsep}` prints `\textfloatsep` ???

Comment: Sorry, but which mode/syntax are all these commands using/expecting? I also cannot add blank spaces inside the \typeout to align the values printed (as in the example code)... Using "\ \ " does insert the blanks but it also prints the backslashes (I suspect due to the presence of the "\string\" earlier in the lines)

Comment: no `\ ` never makes a space token it is an unexpanable primitive which is why it prints as `\ ` you can use `\space` to make a space.

Comment: Got it! All problems solved now. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using latex you can use `^^J` or better `\MessageBreak`, but also you can use `\typeout`  to make each message come on its own line (and protect fragile commands)